# Flickering/jerky/stuttering animation in both Flash and Javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript, flicker, smoothing

Here's a demo:
http://nushuttles.com/chords/player.html

The top square is rendered in Flash, the lower square is animated by Javascript.


As you can probably tell, there is some occasional flickering, jerkiness, or stuttering that occurs every few seconds in both the Flash and Javascript animations. I would imagine this happens because the computer occasionally devotes its resources to another process, leaving Flash player and Javascript hanging for a few milliseconds. I've seen this in plenty of other Flash and Javascript animations, but it only becomes noticeable when you are trying to move something at a constant speed across the screen... which unfortunately is what I need to do.


For the Flash box, I set the "wmode" param for flash player to "direct", which is supposed to provide the best performance. I also used a library called GTween instead of just incrementing the x coordinates. Neither of these were able to stop the stuttering completely.

For the Javascript box, I'm using something called requestAnimationFrame, as described here: http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/. I also tried using a canvas. Still no better.


Is there any way to get a perfectly smooth animation in either Flash or Javascript? Is there any way to get Flash player to give its process a higher priority?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your JavaScript animation was as jerky / flashy as it was.  I used CSS to do a similar animation to yours and it wasn't very jerky and did not exhibit flash.  I put the code [in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G5raR/).

HTML

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="abox"><div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#outer { background-color: black; width: 500px;  height: 500px; }
#abox {
    position: relative; top: 20px;
    background: red;
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
}
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var ttime, $abox, width, toRight;

    ttime = 4000;
    $abox= $("#abox");
    width = $("#outer").outerWidth() - $abox.outerWidth();
    toRight = true;
    function swing() {
        var leftTo = (toRight ? width : 0);
        toRight = !toRight;

        $abox.animate({
            left: leftTo
        }, ttime, function() {
            setTimeout(swing, 50);
        });
    }

    setTimeout(swing, 50);
});
```